# Generating Linq classes from a SQL Compact 3.5 database using SQLMetal

Tags: linq, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework, sqlmetal

I am generating Linq classes by running SQLMetal from the command line against a Compact 3.5 database. The Compact 3.5 database is a local database cache (generated by the Sync Framework "Create Local Database Cache wizard).
CE seems to support foreign keys constraints, but I am not seeing any, and SQLMetal does not generate them into the model.
Generating my model from the source SQL 2008 database and pointing my datacontext to the Compact database does not seem to work.

Is there any way how I can get my associations generated, other than by adding them to the model manually?

Answer (score 2):

Use Entity Framework 4.

```
SqlMetal.exe C:\Metal\CompactDB.sdf /dbml:C:\Metal\CompactDBModel.dbml /Context:ModelDataContext /provider:SQLCompact /pluralize
```